# OnItemClickListener gets neither valid parent id nor view id under ListPopupWindow

Tags: android, xml, listview, view, onitemclicklistener

I have implemented a pair of `EditText`'s and both of them have associated `ListPopopWindow`'s. The `add` Operation works fine, so, I write something on `EditText` Field and I press `enter` Taste of Virtual Keyboard and this value is saved and added to the `ListPopWindow` but what doesn't work so fine, is `onItemClick` Event.
What this Method should do, is writting the value of the item on `EditText` Field but it doesn't do.

I have debugged with LogCat and see that the id's of `parent` and `view` of the typical signature of `onItemClick` :

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
```

return `-1` and I don't understand why, so that I have assigned right id's in my xml-layout-File and I attached right the onItemClickListener to the `ListPopupWindow`'s and I can show on my LogCat the value of `view` and is right, the only problem has to do with `id`'s

Following I post my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnItemClickListener, OnEditorActionListener{


private EditText product_name;
private ArrayAdapter<String> productAdapter;
private ListPopupWindow productListPopupWindow;
private ArrayList<String> products= new ArrayList<String>();


private EditText device;
private ArrayAdapter<String> deviceAdapter;
private ArrayList<String> devices= new ArrayList<String>();
private ListPopupWindow deviceListPopupWindow;


private Context context;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    context = getApplicationContext();

    initAdapters();
    configureActionItem();      

}
```

Rest of code for better legibility

```
private void initAdapters() {
    // Init Product List 
    products.add("JD 000");
    products.add("JD 001");
    products.add("JD 002");
    products.add("JD 003");
    products.add("JD 004");

    // Init Product Adapter
    productListPopupWindow = new ListPopupWindow(MainActivity.this);
    productAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this,R.layout.product_list_item, products);
    productListPopupWindow.setAdapter(productAdapter);

    // ****************************
    // Init Device List 
    devices.add("DEV000");
    devices.add("DEV001");
    devices.add("DEV002");
    devices.add("DEV003");
    devices.add("DEV004");

    // Init Device Adapter
    deviceListPopupWindow = new ListPopupWindow(MainActivity.this);
    deviceAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this,R.layout.device_list_item, devices);
    deviceListPopupWindow.setAdapter(deviceAdapter);        
}

private void configureActionItem() {
    product_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_product);

    productListPopupWindow.setAnchorView(product_name);
    productListPopupWindow.setWidth(300);
    productListPopupWindow.setHeight(400);

    productListPopupWindow.setModal(true);
    productListPopupWindow.setOnItemClickListener( MainActivity.this); <- attached Listener

    product_name.setOnEditorActionListener(MainActivity.this);
    product_name.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);

    // --------------------------------------------------------------
    device = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_device_implement);

    deviceListPopupWindow.setAnchorView(device);
    deviceListPopupWindow.setWidth(300);
    deviceListPopupWindow.setHeight(400);

    deviceListPopupWindow.setModal(true);
    deviceListPopupWindow.setOnItemClickListener( MainActivity.this); <- attached Listener

    device.setOnEditorActionListener(MainActivity.this);
    device.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);       
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    // It's the same: parent.getId() or view.getId(), both of them return -1
    switch ( parent.getId()) { 
        case R.id.edit_text_product :
            product_name.setText(products.get(position));
            productListPopupWindow.dismiss();
        break;              
        case R.id.edit_text_device_implement :
            device.setText(devices.get(position));
            deviceListPopupWindow.dismiss();
        break;
    }   
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // If I click on EditText Field, then ListPopupWindow will be expanded and shown
    switch ( v.getId()) {
        case R.id.edit_text_product :
            productListPopupWindow.show();
        break;              
        case R.id.edit_text_device_implement :
            deviceListPopupWindow.show();
        break;  
    }       
}

@Override
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event == null || event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {

        switch ( v.getId()) {
            case R.id.edit_text_product :
                productAdapter.add(v.getText().toString());
                v.setText("");
                productListPopupWindow.show();
            break;              
            case R.id.edit_text_device_implement :
                deviceAdapter.add(v.getText().toString());
                v.setText("");
                deviceListPopupWindow.show();
            break;              
        }


        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);

      }

      return(true);
}
```

And last my `xml`'s

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text_product"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:imeOptions="actionGo"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="12dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text_device_implement"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:imeOptions="actionGo"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="12dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

und xml Layout of items

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="6dp"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

**Can anyone tell me what I do wrong?**

I thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved.**

The reason, why I got -1 was, the `view` on

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
```

had no associated `id`, so, the way to solve this issue is the following
(I just post one list_item layout but we need a list_item layout for each adapter, they differs just in the `id` to distinguish in switch of `onItemClick` Method, so, write self properly the id  )

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/id_you_want" <- What I added
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="6dp"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Then I replaced 3 lines in `onItemClick`

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {

```
// It's the same: parent.getId() or view.getId(), both of them return -1
switch ( view.getId()) {  // What I replaced
    case R.id.id_you_want_1: // What I replaced 
        product_name.setText(products.get(position));
        productListPopupWindow.dismiss();
    break;              
    case R.id.id_you_want_2: // What I replaced 
        device.setText(devices.get(position));
        deviceListPopupWindow.dismiss();
    break;
}   
}
```